# How do I re-start my observer if onError is called for my subscription?

Tags: rx-java

I am currently using:

```
PublishSubject<PubNubObserverData> = PublishSubject.create()
```

I was wondering how I can restart the subscription when

```
onError(Throwable e)
```

is called by?

Currently the subscription stops when there is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `retry()` operator to automatically re-subscribe immediately. Alternatively, you can use `retryWhen()` operator to resubscribe after a delay or only conditionally.

```
observable
  .retryWhen( error -> error.flatMap( e -> Observable.timer(1, SECONDS))
```

will retry the subscription after 1 second. Using `flatMap()` you could also test the kind of error and only retry on a particular error.

```
observable
  .retryWhen( error -> error.flatMap( e -> { 
    if (e instanceof IOException) {return Observable.timer(1, SECONDS);}
      return Observable.just( e );
    } )
```

will retry if the error is `IOException` and not for any other type of error.